# Why isn't vue-loader working with storybook?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, storybook

I am using `vuetify` with `storybook`.

When I try to view my components (in storybook only - they work fine in my vue app) I receive this error:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not
>   defined.

My `webpack.config.js` file for storybook looks like this:

```
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin')
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()

  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },

    ]
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Just try `npm add -D @andoshin11/storybook-vue3`, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

There is already "@storybook/vue" from development dependencies.